# Drupal migration :: Routing/dispatching issues or permission issues?

Tags: php, apache, drupal

I have a multi site drupal installation that I am having issues with on 'the new server'. I can get it to work perfect on my dev system. On the dev system I use a virtualhost (apache), with the /etc/hosts pointing back to 127.... I setup the same virtualhost, and DB on the server (same builiding) and use DNS forwarding on the router pointing the URL to the web server. All request go to the web server now, even from outside (with same bad behavior). The front page of the drupal site will display, but nothing else, except that I can do an 'update.php' on the install. The apache error log shows this:

```
[Mon Apr 18 15:10:46 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.199] File does not exist: /var/www/maxxdev.homeip.net/im, referer: http://maxxdev.homeip.net/


[Mon Apr 18 15:09:02 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.199] File does not exist: /var/www/maxxdev.homeip.net/im, referer: http://maxxdev.homeip.net/ACT
```

My settings.php is fine, has the right domain name and DB connection is fine too. Somewhere the requests are getting mangled (I think), Also if I walk right up to the server and try to surf to the site (using text browser), I still get the same bad behavior.

The firePHP shows that any GET request sent to the site results in a 404 not found, with the exception of all the front page stuff. Also I should mention that cache is disabled (drupal cache). I cannot figure this out...

Is the drupal dispatch, front controller not happy with DNS fowarding, or could it be having issues with the apache virtualhost? Or could I just be having issues with file permissions? My browser will actuall request something like .../node/74 but it does not seem to make it to Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

Turn off clean URLs, & all is fine now.

I turned them off manually by accessing the DB (phpmyadmin). The 'variable' table contains the settings for this, I changed the '1' to a '0' in the the row that has the 'clean-urls' setting.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like mod rewrite isn't working on the web server.

1) Make sure the .htaccess file got pushed to the web server.  It should live in the web root.

2) Make sure your apache config (assuming you're using apache) is set to AllowOverride on that directory.

Note, to confirm this, you could probably pull up a page using: http://example.com/index.php?q=node/74

Comment: If you go a while without being able to turn on mod rewrite (if you have to ask someone else to turn it on), you can also turn off url rewriting / "short urls" in the configuration options somewhere.

Comment: I was actually looking at the .htaccess file earlier as well. I voted your answer up because it could have been the problem as well, but is a useful response, thanks.